# object mongodb is not a member of package com

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0

After run i getting this object mongodb is not a member of package com in Play 
I cant resolve that problem. Im trying to do Play Scala MongoDB and from client side Scala.js 
my build.sbt is >

```
lazy val server = (project in file("server")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  scalaJSProjects := clients,
  pipelineStages := Seq(scalaJSProd, gzip),
  resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.vmunier" %% "play-scalajs-scripts" % "0.3.0",
    "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "3.1.0",
    "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.11.1",
    "com.novus" %% "salat" % "1.9.9",
    "se.radley" %% "play-plugins-salat" % "1.5.0",
    "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6",
    specs2 % Test
```

object code

```
package model

import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject

/**
  * Created by qqQQaAs on 2016-01-04.
  */
object AllBooks {

  def toJson() {
    val collection = MongoConnection()("books")("books")
    val query = "Krakow"
    // simply convert the result to a string, separating items with a comma
    // this string goes inside an "array", and it's ready to hit the road
    val json = "[%s]".format(
      collection.find(query).toList.mkString(",")
    )
  }
```

Controller

```
package controllers


import com.mongodb.casbah._
import model.AllBooks
import play.api.mvc._
import shared.SharedMessages

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(SharedMessages.itWorks))
  }

  def service() = Action {

    val json = AllBooks.toJson()

    Ok(json).as("application/json")

  }
}
```

Thanks for help guys

Answer (score 1):

You should import the following pages as per the official [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/3.1/):

```
import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.bson._
```